# How to set pagination for Rest API using mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, groovy

I have tried below code

In Controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addressBook/getall/{index}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
PageDto getAddressBookPagination(@PathVariable int index) {
    log.info("Rest Controller Get getAddressBookPagination");
    return addressBookService.getAddressBookPagination(index);
}
```

In Service:-

```
PageDto getAddressBookPagination(int index) {
    PageDto var =new PageDto()
    Pageable page=new PageRequest(index,4)
    List<AddressBook> addressBookList =addressBookRepository.findPagination(page)
    List<AddressBook> totalList = addressBookRepository.findAll();
    var.list=AddressBookDTOConversion.toAddressBookDTO(addressBookList);
    var.totalRow = totalList.size();
    return var;
}
```

In Entity Class having method :-

```
@Query("{db.AddressBook.find().pretty()}")
List<AddressBook> findPagination(Pageable page)
```

Getting the error: `Error creating bean with name 'addressBookController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;`

But this concept is running for mysql DB while I have to use in mongoDB. Please help me...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This is the error...........   Error creating bean with name 'addressBookController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Comment: one more error......             No property findPagination found for type AddressBook!